# AutoResetEvents locking main thread while waiting on event handler

Tags: c#, wait, autoresetevent

Brief explanation is I am attempting to start several connection events with a third party DLL i have no control over. Once a connection happens an event is fired.

I need to wait on the main thread until this happens however every time I set this up it locks the main thread.

```
private EventWaitHandle _waitForChannel = new AutoResetEvent(false);
```

Calling Code

```
new Thread(StartInstrumentMonitoring).Start();
```

=------------------

```
public void StartInstrumentMonitoring(){
if(this.instrumentList.Count == 0){
    new Thread(startConnections).Start()
_waitForChannel.WaitOne();
```

=-----------------------------

```
public void startCOnnections(){
 CODE HERE TO DETERMINE INSTRUMENT
 instrument.connectionReceived += instrument_connectionEvent;

instrument_connectionEvent(object sender, ResultEventArgs e){

            if (sender.Name == instrument.Identifier || sender.Identifier == instrument.Identifier)
                _waitForChannel.Set();
}
```

The problem with this code, is that on execution StartInstrumentMonitoring returns after it makes the necessary calls out to the third party DLL and attaches the event handlers to interact with said library. which obviously calls WaitOne() which blocks the main thread I am on preventing me from catching the events returned from the `instrument_ConnectionEvent`

Answer (score 0):

If the `instrument_ConnectionEvent` is not being called at all it is certainly possible that the 3rd party library is trying to trigger the event back on the main thread which would lead to a deadlock with your current code.

Instead of an `AutoResetEvent` you could use a simple conditional check to see if your connections are established. You can call `Application.DoEvents()` in a loop to force processing the message queue.

```
while(<check condition> == false)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Comment: it is definitely a deadlock event, However the DoEvents has been depreciated in WPF, any ideas what the equivelant would be.

Comment: Didn't realize it was WPF...you might just want to change how your code is structured. Is their any reason you can't perform the logic that you want to trigger after the connection is started in the `instrument_ConnectionEvent`?

Comment: there is, The `instrument_ConnectionEvent` only ever fired once per instrument, the secondary logic that is deadlocking is part of a test system, it allows us to test specific aspects of each instrument, so it can be called 4-5 times per instrument.